# How to add bar chart inside tablix column of SSRS report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have one SSRS report contains tablix and inside tablix I need to put one column which has structure as bar chart. Depends on column value bar chart should vary in size. I heard something about Data region however I am not able to find it in SSRS report. Please provide any help or useful link for same.

Comment: Check Data bar component. Just put it in tablix column.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for adding a bar chart inside a tablix column in SSRS:

http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/08/ssrs-example-for-tablix-with-sparkline.html